# Git-add : Marking files to add without entering full path

Tags: git, git-add

Does anyone knows a cli utility or command that allow to quickly mark files to add to the next commit or rebase ?

For now i have to do :

```
git add $fullPath0 $fullPath1 $fullPath2...
```

I heard that "tig" can open a window where you can add files with spacebar key but i can't find anything about this command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something with the "tig" utility :

execute this in terminal :

```
tig status
```

Navigate up or down with arrow keys then press "u" to stage (add) the files.

You can press "u" again to unstage the files.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add all the files in a particular folder, you can use a wildcard:

```
git add path/to/folder/*
```

Comment: You can also use autocomplete (tab key), if your command line/terminal supports it.  Most do.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, except:
git add */some_file_in_some_directory.whatever